# MVC3, custom object lists and searching

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns

I'm new to MVC3 (and MVC in general) and looking for a bit of advice.  Pointing me in the direction of some good articles or tutorials would be good enough I think. I'm a bit familiar with the concept of MVC, and I've been a c# programmer (hobbyist and partly professional) for a while now.

The issue I have is that I have an object (call it "Game"), which has a `List<T>` as a property (call T "Player"), and I want the user to "select" the player to add them to the Game.

All players would be managed in another part of the application, so there is no need to think about "managing" the master player pool at this point.

I'm looking for a best practice for:

1. adding custom objects to a list that of n length while on a page.
2. Searching for and selecting a custom object in the first place.

I can do the standard pages for the database access so that's not a problem.  In asp I would have just done something like a wizard and managed everything through postback on the page, but I want to try and keep to best practice where i can for this project.

Any pointers welcome, also looking for some good physical books to buy on MVC.

Comment: Steve Sanderson's book is a good startup, at least it was for me. There are videos on tekpub by Steve Sanderson and Rob Conery which basically repeat the book but are very entertaining. I think these two resources might be enough for a start-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want two elements within the page, a player search (over all players) and a list of players already added to the game.

For the player search you want to use a bit of jQuery to hook up an actionResult that returns a JSON result of your player results. You can then display these results without having to leave the page, in appearance much like an AJAX post in webforms.

You have more options for how you add the player to the game, depending on if you want to add more than one at once, or want a backout stage (so you can "add" players and then cancel out and they won't be added).

the option I think would give the most seamless interface would be a jQuery/javascript call to an action method which datawise adds your player to the game, and use jQuery to add the element to your players in the game on the page.

For the adding of a player in your controller you could return a bool in a JSON result, just you have confirmation that the player was successfully added to the list.

For reference: This is quite an old article but highlights the power of working with jQuery and MVC quite nicely I think http://andreasohlund.net/2008/12/21/asp-net-mvc-jquery-true/